# Как сделать перевод USDT TRC20, используя приватный ключ?

Tags: python

Для теста был сгенерирован приватный ключ:
4a30a46d65518dae8b77165018dda96979188f14779b6f8fc51d493a9cbef44a

```
import ecdsa
sk = ecdsa.SigningKey.generate(curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)
private_key = sk.to_string().hex()
```

Дальше был сгенерирован адрес TRC20:

```
TDwZSFxbnRqHEwwtgCuB63reTUWz2yXGrf
```

(Алгоритм описан тут - https://developers.tron.network/docs/account)

Допустим, потом на него перевели 100$ (USDT), с binance.com, используя сеть Tron (TRC20), теперь, каким образом (программно, естественно) сделать перевод С этого кошелька на другой USDT TRC20 адрес?

В документации https://developers.tron.network/ по большей части указано как делать переводы TRX (трона), но как перевести Tether, используя их сеть?

Насколько я понимаю, тут необходимо создавать смартконтракты? Или возможно это сделать проще? В идеале, сделать один запрос с приватным ключом, получателем и суммой платежа. Есть ли какие-то комиссии при переводах?

Возможно я использовал неверные термины при описании проблемы, но надеюсь, что вы поняли суть.

Comment: я сейчас столкнулся с этой задачей. Ты не нашел ее решение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитай официальную документацию трон.
https://developers.tron.network/reference/triggersmartcontract

вот пример кода на Python

```
import requests

url = "https://api.shasta.trongrid.io/wallet/triggersmartcontract"

payload = {
    "owner_address": "41D1E7A6BC354106CB410E65FF8B181C600FF14292",
    "contract_address": "41a7837ce56da0cbb28f30bcd5bff01d4fe7e4c6e3",
    "function_selector": "transfer(address,uint256)",
    "call_value": 0
}
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```